# QueryString not visible in Request

Tags: asp.net, httphandler, webforms, webrequest

I am writing HttpHandler and I am not able to access to QueryString in Request object (QueryString is empty). I am not sure is it problem encoding or something else.

Sample of URL ( method is GET )

http://localhost/reportserver?%2fReports.Test%2fUserView&rs:SessionID=xz1mcizuiahcfcew2nklm4i3&rs:command=Render&rs:Format=RGDI&rc:Page=1&rc:RGDIVersion=10.0.2&rc:Toolbar=false&rs:ErrorResponseAsXml=true&rs:AllowNewSessions=false

web.config

<httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" path="*" type="ProxyWeb.MyProxy"/>
</httpHandlers>

Thanks for help

Comment: how do you try to read ?

Comment: context.Request.QueryString["SomeKey"]

Comment: actually you can read anything after the ? SomeKey is not on the query

Comment: I can read everything (like Headers) except QueryString. SomeKey is sample. I am debugging app so I am inspecting with VS.

Comment: whats is the key youre trying to read ?

Comment: I am debugging app so, I am having break point in handler, and with VS tools inspecting request and QueryString.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution to my problem was to delete all pages from site. From some reason pages are messing up routing to handler.